# ArrayList implementation in PHP

Tags: java, php, arraylist

I have tried implementing the basic features of ArrayList (Java ) in PHP .The Arraylist should be capable of adding any type of object (generic as in Java)
Can anyone give suggestion for improvement in design/implementation. Here is the code

```
<?php
/* 
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

class ArrayList
{

    private $arrVar;

    function  __construct($option)
    {
        $this->arrVar = array();
        array_push($this->arrVar,$option);
    }

  function addValue($option)
  {
      array_push($this->arrVar,$option);
  }

    function getLastValue()
  {
      $arr = array_pop($this->arrVar);
      return $arr;
  }

}



?>
```

Comment: Why can't you use normal PHP arrays? They can contain objects of any type without you having to specify what type.

Comment: need to write some customized functions.

Comment: array_pop deletes the last element of the array, but you function says getLastValue()

Comment: I suspect that the customized functions you want to write could be written using an [`iterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php). [See here for an example of using them with an array of objects](http://giorgiosironi.blogspot.com/2010/02/practical-php-patterns-iterator.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this helps:

```
class MyArray {
   private $my_array;

   function  __construct() {
      $this->my_array = array();
   }

   public function setMyArray($value) {
      $this->my_array = $value;
   }

   public function getMyArray() {
      return $this->my_array;
   }

   public function getLastElement() {
      $last_elem = array_reverse($this->getMyArray());
      return $last_elem[0];
   }
}

$myArr = new MyArray();
$a[] = "Hello"; // use this instead of array_push
$a[] = "World";
$myArr->setMyArray($a);
echo "My Array:<pre>".print_r($myArr->getMyArray(),true)."</pre><br />\n";
echo "Last Element: ".$myArr->getLastElement()."<br />\n";

$a[] = "Yet another element";
$myArr->setMyArray($a);
echo "My Array Again:<pre>".print_r($myArr->getMyArray(),true)."</pre><br />\n";
echo "Last Element Again: ".$myArr->getLastElement()."<br />\n";
```

Output:

```
My Array:Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => World
)

Last Element: World

My Array Again:Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => World
    [2] => Yet another element
)

Last Element Again: Yet another element
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class doesn't really do anything other than restrict the operations I can perform on the array.  It's usually best to adopt the idioms common for a particular language, rather than trying to get the language to resemble some other language you prefer.

Comment: Not to mention that it neither follows the naming conventions for ArrayList nor implements a minimal useful subset of its members.